# Renaming an image during the uploading PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file-rename

Using the following code could someone explain to me how I can rename the image files to a misc name during the upload process?

Here is what I'm working with.

**uploader.php**

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/connections/dbconnect.php");
$dataType = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["dataType"]);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
$fileName = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$target_path = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/gallery/".$fileName);
if (file_exists($target_path))
{
    echo "An image with that file name already exists.";
}
elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_path))
{
    // The file is in the images/gallery folder. Insert record into database by
    // executing the following query:
     $sql="INSERT INTO images (data_type, title, file_name)"."VALUES('$dataType','$title','$fileName')";
     $retval = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "The image was successfully uploaded and added to the gallery :) <a href='index.php'>Add another image</a>";


}
else
{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

---

Then here is my code for uploading the image to the gallery.

---

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">


        Category: <select class="text" name="dataType">
        <option value="treeremoval" selected="selected">treeremoval</option>
        <option value="treetrimming" >treetrimming</option>
        <option value="treebracing" >treebracing</option>
        <option value="stumpgrinding" >stumpgrinding</option>
        <option value="firewood" >firewood</option>
        <option value="cleanup" >cleanup</option>
        </select><br />
<br />




    Caption: <input type="text" name="title"><br />
<br />

    Image to upload: <input type="file" name="image"><br />
<br />




    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I am very new to using php and mysql so any help would be appreciated. I have some other questions too, but I guess I should ask one at a time. =)

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try something like this, you will create a unique id and append the extension of the file to it, if that name exists you loop until you have one that doesn't, then you move the file.

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/connections/dbconnect.php");

$dataType = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["dataType"]);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);

$fileData = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]));

$fileName = uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];

$target_path = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/gallery/" . $fileName);

while(file_exists($target_path))
{
    $fileName = uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];
    $target_path = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/gallery/" . $fileName);
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_path))
{
    // The file is in the images/gallery folder. Insert record into database by
    // executing the following query:
     $sql="INSERT INTO images (data_type, title, file_name)"."VALUES('$dataType','$title','$fileName')";
     $retval = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "The image was successfully uploaded and added to the gallery :) <a href='index.php'>Add another image</a>";


}
else
{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

?>

Comment: That works great thank you very much!!

Was wondering if you have time could you help me with some other things regarding this code? If so email me at chris@pdslo.com or can we chat on here?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)`

Youre `$target_path` is from the variable `$fileName`

Change the filename from

```
$fileName = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

to

```
'myfilename'
```

Comment: So change
`$fileName = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);`

to this
`$myfilename = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);`

Comment: g@daugaard47 what do you want to call your file? Say you want to call it `myfile.jpg`? So `$filename = 'myfile.jpg';`

Comment: I want it to apply random names. 1.jpg 2.jpg doesnt matter. Just need a random name applied, because my client send me images from his iPhone through a form, but each image is called "image". Thats the reason I need the file renamed during upload. In the end I want to be able to upload these images from my admin page to the gallery using my phone.

Comment: @daugaard47 just make sure the file doesnt exist yet with `file_exists()` and then rename it something like you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
$sql =mysql_query("select * from table ");
$result = mysql_num_rows($sql) +1;

$newfilename = rename("$oldfilename", "$newfilename");
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest upload a secure image format and restrict file size

```
           //image upload
            $pro_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $pro_image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

            $fileType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];  
            $fileSize = $_FILES["image"]["size"];  
            $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["image"]["error"];  

             $fileName = preg_replace('#[^a-z.0-9]#i', '', $pro_image); 
             $nwtourimg = explode(".", $fileName);
             if (!$pro_image_tmp) { // if file not chosen
                echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
                exit();
            } else if($fileSize > 5242880) { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
                echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 5 Megabytes in size.";
                unlink($pro_image_tmp); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
                exit();
            } else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$/i", $fileName) ) {
                 // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
                 echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
                 unlink($pro_image_tmp); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
                 exit();
            } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
                echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
                exit();
            }

             $fileExt = end($nwtourimg);
             $fileName = time().rand().".".$fileExt;


             move_uploaded_file("$pro_image_tmp","upload/$fileName");
                //image upload end
```

Answer (score 0):

//image upload
            $pro_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $pro_image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

```
        $fileType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];  
        $fileSize = $_FILES["image"]["size"];  
        $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["image"]["error"];  

         $fileName = preg_replace('#[^a-z.0-9]#i', '', $pro_image); 
         $nwtourimg = explode(".", $fileName);
         if (!$pro_image_tmp) { // if file not chosen
            echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
            exit();
        } else if($fileSize > 5242880) { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
            echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 5 Megabytes in size.";
            unlink($pro_image_tmp); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
            exit();
        } else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$/i", $fileName) ) {
             // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
             echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
             unlink($pro_image_tmp); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
             exit();
        } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
            echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
            exit();
        }

         $fileExt = end($nwtourimg);
         $fileName = time().rand().".".$fileExt;


         move_uploaded_file("$pro_image_tmp","upload/$fileName");
            //image upload end
```